# Young adult/children's book of adventure and mystery where the bad guys are Illuminati

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, childrens-novel

I read this book when I was young, so the book should be intended for this audience. I don't think it is very old, I would say it was published after the 2000s. I read it in Spanish; I don't know the country of origin.

I don't remember much about the story; it was in the present time and the main characters were some friends, maybe two or three, who were involved in a mystery, a riddle to solve. This riddle somehow led them to the Illuminati, who I think were the bad guys in the story.

It might have something to do with video games.

It don't remember magic in the story, but maybe something unrealistic that could be considered science fiction.

Comment: What sort of "something unrealistic"?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots If it doesn't take place in the 18th century, the Illuminati might count.

Comment: True, I guess, but as of now, this feels like a bit of a reach. "Um... not really sure if there's anything site-relevant, but maybe something I don't remember well enough to even vaguely describe?"

Comment: The most revelant thing that I remember it is that some teenage age childs where doing "something" were involved in a problem against the illuminati who control the world from the shadows.